# Visual Studio Code can't find the class that I've declared and defined in C++

Tags: c++, oop, visual-studio-code

I'm getting a linker error when I separate my class declarations and function definitions into their own files. The code gets through the compiler when all the code is in one singular .cpp file, but that's not what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to know how I can separate my code into different files.

Here is all the code. This code runs completely fine.

```
// main.cpp

#include <string>

#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

class Animal {
private:
    std::string name;
    int height;
    int weight;
    std::string color;

public:
    Animal(std::string, int, int);
};

#endif

Animal::Animal(std::string name, int height, int weight) {
    this -> name = name;
    this -> height = height;
    this -> weight = weight;
}

int main() {
    Animal dog("Spotty", 20, 50);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Although, since I want to separate the code, I put the class declaration into it's own file and the function definitions into their own file, and I get this.

```
// main.cpp

#include <string>
#include "Animal.hpp"

int main() {
    Animal dog("Spotty", 20, 50);
    
    return 0;
}



// Animal.hpp

#include <string>

#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

class Animal {
private:
    std::string name;
    int height;
    int weight;
    std::string color;

public:
    Animal(std::string, int, int);
};

#endif



// Animal.cpp

#include "Animal.hpp"

Animal::Animal(std::string name, int height, int weight) {
    this -> name = name;
    this -> height = height;
    this -> weight = weight;
}
```

This is the error I get when I compile the second version of main.cpp.

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "`public: __thiscall Animal::Animal(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int,int)`" (??0Animal@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HH@Z) referenced in function _main
>
> main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Sounds like you need to make sure Animal.cpp is a part of the same Visual Studio "project".

Comment: That is not an error generated during compilation, it is a linker error.  If you are getting it when you are trying to compile, make sure your compiler command line uses the "compile only" option not the "compile then link" option.

Comment: What command are you using to compile the code? It seems you are not including `Animal.cpp` in the input files list.

Comment: I'm just using: cl main.cpp

Comment: @rTaP Then that explains it. that compiles, then links the resulting object code of, `main.cpp`. You need to add `Animal.cpp` to that objective.

Comment: That worked! I didn't know you could compile two things at the same time. Thanks!

Comment: The canonical build sequence here is `cl /c main.cpp` (creates main.obj) `cl /c Animal.cpp` (creates Animal.obj) `link main.obj Animal.obj` (creates main.exe).  You can do all three in one shot with `cl main.cpp Animal.cpp` but it's still good to know the individual steps.

Answer (score -1):

Try giving the parameters in your constructor names.
e.g

```
Animal(std::string name, int h, int w);
```

The constructor doesnt do anything right now. Do you have the function in another file?